# Forecast.io not giving response : Error Forbidden

Tags: web-services, api

I have implemented `Forecast.io` to get weather details. It was working correctly for long time (1.5 year) and recently its not working.

I have regenerated key and tried the url

`https://api.forecast.io/forecast/<key>/37.8267,-122.423`

but its displaying only `Forbidden` message

Whats going wrong?

Comment: did you ever figure this out? having the same issue now

Comment: Forecast.io is being relaunched as darksky.net! Check the official site They are changing something

Answer (score 0):

You are likely out of free API calls.  Log in to your account to see if you've reached the monthly limit.